# Google Maps V3 API Failing

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Starting on Sept 10, our request for geocoding addresses has been failing with the message

> We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending
>   automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request
>   right now.

This process has been running since the beginning of June without a problem. It geocodes no more than 1 address every 2 seconds between the hours of 4AM-4PM, fewer during the other hours, and limits to 2500/day. When I looked through the logs I see that the change went from normal geocoding to this message between requests that were 32 seconds apart. There was no intervening 620 response.
September 10, 2013 9:40:36 PM -- Success
September 10, 2013 9:41:08 PM -- Failure

According to the Google Map API documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat, I should be running an automated query.

Is there some technical problem with the service?
Did something change in the policies that has not been reflected in the documentation?
Has something else happened?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably using the v2 geocoder, which was deprecated in 2010 and has now been turned down.  See [this post](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/an-update-on-geocoding-api-v2.html) for more info, and [the upgrade guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade) to migrate.

If this isn't your issue, please include a request you're making to the service which is failing.

Comment: This was exactly our situation. Thanks for the clue to helping us fix the issue on our site.

Answer (score -1):

You're still breaking the TOS by automating queries, regardless of query limits. This is what happens when you do that.